# My Own Constraint Validator as service

Tags: validation, symfony

I'm trying to build a custom validator running as a service (mainly for getting the entity manager).

I followed the doc and some blog posts but can't make it working. I have this error

```
    Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to 
D\AjaxBundle\Validator\Constraints\SelectTypeValidator::__construct() must implement 
interface Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager, none given, called in 
/AJAX/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Validator/ConstraintValidatorFactory.php on line 67 and defined in 
/AJAX/src/D/AjaxBundle/Validator/Constraints/SelectTypeValidator.php line 14
```

services.yml

```
    validator.selectType:
        class: D\AjaxBundle\Validator\Constraints\SeletTypeValidator
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
        tags:
            - { name: validator.selectType, alias: selectType }
```

SelectTypeValidator:

```
namespace D\AjaxBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class SelectTypeValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    private $om;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $om)
    {
        $this->om = $om;
    }

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $fieldOne = $this->om->getRepository('DAjaxBundle:City')->findOneBy(array('id' =>
                $value->getId()));

        if ($fieldOne == null) {
            $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message, array('%string%' => $value->
                    getId()));
        }
    }
}
```

SelectType

```
namespace D\AjaxBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

class SelectType extends Constraint
{
    public $message ='jakis text';

    public function validateBy()
    {
        return 'selectType';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The service tag name should be `validator.constraint_validator` instead of `validator.selectType`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this'll make a difference but it's worth a try...I never wrap service arguments with quotes:

```
arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```